# Android app unable to start activity componentinfo android.content.res.Resources$NotFound

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here's the entire logcat stack trace:

```
08-23 02:19:52.826  20628-20628/com.example.sham_tech.lastchance E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sham_tech.lastchance, PID: 20628
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sham_tech.lastchance/com.example.sham_tech.lastchance.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File    res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2152)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
        at   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354)
        at   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
        at   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawable Manager.java:181)
         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689)
        at   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:  77)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>  (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at 
com.example.sham_tech.lastchance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
```

I cannot understand what's the problem!.

Here's the activity_main.xml

```
  <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:text="Quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="SubmitOrder"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there anything wrong in the code?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sham_tech.lastchance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    display(1);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
}
```

I have tried to solve it for more than 4 days and there is no result. Please help me!

Comment: how do you import the support library in your project?

Comment: Do you mean the path ? @njzk2

Comment: what path? I mean what method do you use to include the support library in your build?

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: not that part. How is the library included in your project?

Comment: sorry, i'm very new to android. so, i don't understand what do you mean excactly :)

Comment: do you use `compile` in gradle?

Comment: @njzk2  
yes, now i understand :). i use dependencies { compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's looking for a file named "abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml" in your res/drawable/ directory and it's not finding it. Make sure you have that file in that location.

Comment: actually i checked it and it was found !

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted here did not have referenced the

```
abc_ic_ab_back_material
```

1. If you have used it in the other code, so find if you have the resource named **abc_ic_ab_back_material** under **res/drawable/**, if not found, just get one.
2. If you did not have used it anywhere, just **clean** you project and **rebuild**.

Comment: yes i have it  in my  drawable file , what can i do ?

Comment: @Yasmine Mohamed did you use it in your code, XML file or JAVA file?

Comment: @Cobian no, i didn't use it in any one of them.

Comment: @Yasmine Mohamed Ok, you can delete abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml and then clean project and rebuild project

Comment: @Yasmine Mohamed did you have clean your project and rebuild it?

Comment: @Yasmine Mohamed How about pack your project and send it to me? armtrustzone@gmail.com

Comment: @Yasmine, I create a new project and just copy the file you send to me, and then build the project. It launched successfully on the phone and just worked well!

Comment: @cobian i replied on ur email  please check it :).